# I am not able to get dependencies for my flutter project - Flutter pub get issues

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

How can i resolve this error, please I need help to get this resolved.

I am using the flutter dev channel
How can I resolve this error, please I need help to get this resolved.
Tried flutter channel dev also tried to flutter upgrade but nothing worked.

Please help me with it thanks

```
 Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on async 2.6.1 and fstore depends on async 2.5.0, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
    So, because fstore depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
```

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: fstore
publish_to: "none"
description: Mobile commerce app by Flutter
# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 2.1.0+3018
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
# Base
pedantic: ^1.11.0
intl: 0.17.0
# COMMON
inspireui:
path: ./modules/common_library
rubber:
git:
url: git://github.com/inspireui/rubber
country_pickers:
git:
url: git://github.com/inspireui/country_pickers.git
# FIREBASE PACKAGES
firebase_core: 1.1.0
firebase_analytics: 8.0.2
firebase_auth: 1.1.2
cloud_firestore: 1.0.7
firebase_remote_config: 0.9.0-dev.0
firebase_dynamic_links: 2.0.2
firestore_ui:
git:
url: git://github.com/inspireui/firestore_ui.git
# STATE MANAGEMENT
provider: 5.0.0
get_it: 6.1.1
event_bus: 2.0.0
# SPLASH SCREEN, ONBOARDING
animated_splash: 1.0.0
custom_splash: 0.0.2
flare_splash_screen: 4.0.0
rive: 0.7.3
liquid_swipe: 2.1.0
# UI
animated_text_kit: 4.2.1
animations: 2.0.0
awesome_card: 1.1.5
carousel_pro: 1.0.0
configurable_expansion_tile: 1.0.0
country_code_picker: 2.0.1
flash: 1.5.2
flutter_spinkit: 5.0.0
flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.4.0
flutter_statusbarcolor: 0.2.3
flutter_swiper: 1.1.6
visibility_detector: 0.2.0
font_awesome_flutter: 9.0.0
file_picker: 3.0.1
page_indicator: 0.4.1
percent_indicator: 3.0.1
pull_to_refresh: 1.6.5
rate_my_app: ^1.1.0+1
cupertino_icons: any
implicitly_animated_reorderable_list: 0.4.0
pin_code_fields: 7.0.0
# WEB TOOLS
html_unescape: 2.0.0
webview_flutter: 2.0.4
flutter_widget_from_html: 0.6.0
flutter_webview_plugin: 0.3.11
responsive_builder: 0.4.1
# MAP
google_maps_flutter: 2.0.3
location: 2.3.5
# STORAGE
localstorage: ^4.0.0+1
# CONNECTIVITY
http: 0.13.2
http_auth: 1.0.0
uni_links: 0.4.0
share: 2.0.1
# AUTHENTICATION
apple_sign_in: 0.1.0
flutter_facebook_login: 3.0.0
google_sign_in: 5.0.2
sms_autofill: 2.0.0
# PUSH NOTIFICATION
firebase_messaging: 9.1.3
notification_permissions: 0.5.0
onesignal_flutter: 2.6.3
# PAYMENTS
stripe_sdk:
git:
url: git://github.com/inspireui/stripe-sdk.git
razorpay_flutter: 1.2.5
# IMAGES
transparent_image: 2.0.0
extended_image: 4.0.1
fwfh_cached_network_image: 0.6.0
image_picker: 0.7.4
multi_image_picker: 4.8.0
flutter_image_compress: 1.0.0
# VIDEOS
video_player: 2.1.1
youtube_player_iframe:
git:
url: git://github.com/inspireui/youtube_player_flutter.git
path: packages/youtube_player_iframe
# ADS
facebook_audience_network: 0.7.1
google_mobile_ads: 0.12.1+1
# TOOLS
auto_size_text: 2.1.0
google_fonts: 2.0.0
random_string: 2.1.0
json_annotation: 4.0.1
timeago: 3.0.2
universal_platform: ^1.0.0-nullsafety
uuid: 3.0.4
validate: 1.7.0
vector_math: any
async: 2.5.0
easy_debounce: 2.0.0
charts_flutter: 0.10.0
devicelocale: ^0.4.1
dev_dependencies:
flutter_driver:
sdk: flutter
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
version: any
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter
test: any
flutter_launcher_icons: 0.8.1
mockito: ^4.1.1 # Testing
#  vm_service: 5.5.0
## Enable To run json serializer, run:
## flutter pub run build_runner build --build-filter="lib/models/serializers/*.dart" --delete-conflicting-outputs
## flutter pub run build_runner serve --build-filter="lib/models/serializers/*.dart"
#  build_runner: 1.12.2
#  json_serializable: 4.1.0
### Override the library to support Flutter 2.0
### Note: This will show the warning but will not impact to the app features 
dependency_overrides:
intl: 0.17.0
http: 0.13.2
crypto: 3.0.1
path_provider: 2.0.1
uuid: 3.0.4
http_parser: 4.0.0
pedantic: 1.11.0
flutter_svg: 0.19.3
url_launcher: 6.0.1
cached_network_image: 2.5.1
modal_bottom_sheet: 2.0.0
args: 2.1.0
# Run this script to generate the app icon: flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
flutter_icons:
android: "launcher_icon"
ios: true
image_path: "assets/images/app_icon.png"
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
uses-material-design: true
assets:
- lib/config/
- lib/config/mocks/
- lib/config/states/
- lib/config/stories/
- assets/icons/categories/
- assets/icons/credit_cards/
- assets/icons/tabs/
- assets/icons/payment/
- assets/images/
- assets/images/country/
- assets/images/favicon/
- assets/html/
- assets/google_fonts/
fonts:
- family: Feather
fonts:
- asset: assets/fonts/Feather.ttf
- family: SF Pro Display
fonts:
- asset: assets/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Semibold.otf
weight: 700
# An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
# https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
# For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
# https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages
# To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
# in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
# "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
# list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
# example:
#
# For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
# see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
flutter_intl:
enabled: true
```

Flutter Doctor Results

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.3.0-12.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440], locale en-PK)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
• No issues found!
```

Comment: Wooaah thats lot of dependencies :0 ( can see mine as well xD )
For the issue try to change the async version to `2.6.1` or `Flutter upgrade` command.